# Adjust amount of padding and speed of scrolling when calling .Focus() on a control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a control that is a bit longer than the screen. Users move content from the left side of the screen into this control on the right. When the user moves something over, we would like to highlight where the content went.

Currently I can easily do this by just setting .Focus() on the control it fills in.

With just setting Focus, if the control was off screen, focusing on it just brings it to the very top or bottom of the window.

1. Is there any way to possibly pad this a little bit, so that when a control gets focus, it focuses that control as well as gives about 50px padding from the windows edge?
2. Also, is there any way to animate the scroll, so rather than just jumping to the field the window will actually scroll if needed?
3. Finally, is there any event that I can handle (like Focused() or RecievedFocus() or OnFocus() ) when a control gets focus? I would also like to possibly highlight the field that was focused, and figured if I could handle the event it would be easily to do this highlight, as well as #1 above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1: If you want to adjust the padding around your control, you can manually call the BringIntoView event, which WPF calls automatically when you focus the control.  BringIntoView has a TargetRect parameter, which you can inflate a bit to get the padding you want.  MSDN documentation [is here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598115.aspx)

Part 2: I used OnxyFire's code within this [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cd724d5e-ae67-4eb5-921e-05bd913b202b/).  You will need to override the control's style and replace the standard ScrollViewer with an AnimatedScrollViewer. You will also need to provide a RequestBringIntoView event handler (on the class you are bringing into view) to intercept the standard calls to adjust the HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset.  In this case you would call AnimatedScrollViewer.ScrollToPosition() inside your RequestBringIntoView handler  (you could also provide the padding you want from Part 1 within this method, if you choose).

Part 3: Hopefully @svrist has you covered...

Comment: I started implementing #1, but is there a 'best way' to get the Rectangle for a control? A textbox has a GetRectFromCharacterIndex which worked for me, but not sure if that is correct. And ComboBoxes don't have a similar method.

Comment: I also found VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendentBounds which has been more reliable for other control types.

Comment: @jmlumpkin: Try this: var rect = new Rect(element.RenderSize); rect.Inflate(1,1); element.BringIntoView(rect);

Comment: RenderSize worked great, and even better than what I was using.

Comment: GotFocus doesn't work with BringIntoView, so that didn't work.

Comment: So where do you stand now?  What works and what doesn't?  You can try handling the RequestBringIntoView event, and enlarge your targetRect there to provide the padding.  You don't even need to call BringIntoView then because .Focus will do that for you.

Comment: What I ended up doing is writing my own method that does it all for me. I pass the control (listview, combobox, or textbox) and it calls BringIntoView() on that control with a custom Rect using control.RenderSize. I then do the highlighting I want on the control, and then done. Therefore now I don't need to call Focus or handle GotFocus in my case. I also have this one method that handles all the types of controls in this UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

The event is called `GotFocus`. You can do all sorts of animation with a storyboard. MS Expression Blend simplifies that process along with [`VisualStateManager.GotoState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

You might need to set `IsTabStop`on your control for it to consistently receive focus.